# How to get the number of a duplicate list using python?

Tags: python, pandas

here are some difficult problems for me.

Now, I have a dataframe in python. It looks like this:

```
chromosome_id  start_site  stop_site strand          gene_id
0                   1       12228      12612      +  ENST00000456328
1                   1       12722      13220      +  ENST00000456328
2                   1       12058      12178      +  ENST00000450305
3                   1       12228      12612      +  ENST00000450305
4                   1       12698      12974      +  ENST00000450305
```

In the last column,there are some duplicates. I want to get a new column that tell me the time of duplication. like this
1
2
1
2
3

I don't know if I clearly expressed it. For another example, I have a list ,such as "apple  apple  apple banana banana orange orange orange orange ". Then I want to get a new list like this "1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4"

How can I do this by python?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Much better with the bananas an oranges :) Use `df.groupby('gene_id').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It did solve my problem! Thank you!